# How to Handle Two Activities with Two layouts in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android Application I have two Activities.

One is `GmapsActivity` and one is `GmapsActivity1`  and two layouts `login.xml` and `main.xml`

By default I want to load `login.xml` and then in this I want to call `main.xml` on different conditions of password. But when I call `GmapsActivity1` application crashed.  Here is my code sample for `GmapsActivity`

```
public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

EditText password;
Button   login;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login);

        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logbtn);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myIntent = null;
                if(password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GMapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "invalid password - try again",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });

    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

        return false;
    }


    }
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Have you added your both activity in manifest file ?

Comment: In second Activity setContentView(R.layout.SecondActivityXML);

Comment: @ USer15...2 it is a bad code, you are doing everything wrong here, calling activity within the same activity. Follow my answer.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so you have

**GMapsActivity.java** with `login.xml`  and **GmapsActivity1** with `main.xml`

first of all change your manifeste like this

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
                    </category>
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GmapsActivity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

then your **GMapsActivity.java** should like this

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //..some code here..
     }

@Override  
 public void onClick(View v) {  
  Intent i = new Intent(GMapsActivity.this, GmapsActivity1.class);  
  startActivity(i);  
 }
```

and finally your **GmapsActivity1.java** should be like this

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //..some code here..
     }
```

also you may like to check below simple tutorial to understand this

[**Start/Load Activity from Activity in Android**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/04/start-activity-from-activity.html)

still have any doubt, let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
myIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this one and add both activities in your `Manifest.xml`

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    public void onClick(View v) {               
      Intent intent = new Intent(GMapsActivity .this,YourActivityTwo.class);                        
      startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login);

    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logbtn);

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent myIntent = null;
            if(password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
            myIntent = new Intent(GMapsActivity1.this, GMapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "invalid password - try again",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    });

}



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code you are in `GmapsActivity` and in the login button click you are calling

```
myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GMapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
```

Which in terms again starting GmapsAvtivity. as Intent constructor take second parameter as  **another activity name** not the same one.

You should follow below steps to make it working.

1) Create a activity LoginActivity, show login form in it, on Login button click check user/id/password and if it is correct, Call startActivity and startGmapsActivity.

2) Create GmapsActivity, and show whatever you want to show after login screen.

3) Register both activities in manifest file.

**Never ever call setContentView twice in the same activity it is not recommanded**

Comment: Sorry Sir My Mistake I Have Changed the Code But Issue is Still Same

Comment: Issue can not be same, create different activities as suggested.